# Не открывается кабинет разработчика

Tags: cookie

```
Страница недоступна. Сайт passport.yandex.ru выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.
Удалите файлы cookie.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F12 - Application - Coockies - url нужного сайта - ПКМ - Clear

Comment: спасибо большое, правда у меня мак

Comment: на маке нет браузеров с панелью кода элемента?

Comment: Я почистила в браузере куки конкретного сайта